# How to Print From List of maps that include another list of maps?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
var questions = [
        {
          'Text':'What is Your Name?',
          'Answers':[
            {'Answer':'Ahmed', 'Score':10},
            {'Answer':'Moh', 'Score':30},
            {'Answer':'Saif', 'Score':20},
          ]
        },
        {
          'Text':'What is Your Age?',
          'Answers':[
            {'Answer':12, 'Score':10},
            {'Answer':21, 'Score':30},
            {'Answer':23, 'Score':20},
          ]
        },
        {
          'Text':'Who is the best?',
          'Answers':[
            {'Answer':'Zingar','Score':10},
            {'Answer':'Sakr','Score':30},
            {'Answer':'Taw','Score':20},
          ]
        },
      ];
```

Hello everyone , I am new flutter so I might sound stupid .. so bear with me,
I am trying to use  print(questions[0]['Answers'][0]) , to print the first index of 'Answers' Value but it doesn't work , I was wondering how can I print the answers of each questions and the score or how to access them in the first place

Comment: it works fine for me [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/215ba63265350c02dfbd586dfd30b8c3)

Answer (score 1):

Here...

https://dartpad.dev/8dce61c4507566ceccacb0591765f581

```
void main() {
List<Map<String, dynamic>> questions = [
        {
          'Text':'What is Your Name?',
          'Answers':[
            {'Answer':'Ahmed', 'Score':10},
            {'Answer':'Moh', 'Score':30},
            {'Answer':'Saif', 'Score':20},
          ]
        },
        {
          'Text':'What is Your Age?',
          'Answers':[
            {'Answer':12, 'Score':10},
            {'Answer':21, 'Score':30},
            {'Answer':23, 'Score':20},
          ]
        },
        {
          'Text':'Who is the best?',
          'Answers':[
            {'Answer':'Zingar','Score':10},
            {'Answer':'Sakr','Score':30},
            {'Answer':'Taw','Score':20},
          ]
        },
      ];
  
  questions.forEach((q){
    print(q["Text"]);
    //   print(q["Answers"]);  if you want...
    var a = q["Answers"];
    a.forEach((a){
      print(a["Answer"]);
      print(a["Score"]);
    });
    
  }
 );
}
```

Explaining. what forEach does is scan an array giving you each object in that array. So, in:

```
  questions.forEach((q){
```

Each (q) return an object type:

```
{
  'Text':'What is Your Name?',
  'Answers':[
         {'Answer':'Ahmed', 'Score':10},
         {'Answer':'Moh', 'Score':30},
         {'Answer':'Saif', 'Score':20},
       ]
},
```

When you do:

```
   var a = q["Answers"]
```

This return to you an array again:

```
  [
      {'Answer':'Ahmed', 'Score':10},
      {'Answer':'Moh', 'Score':30},
      {'Answer':'Saif', 'Score':20},
  ]
```

And again you can do a forEach to access each object of that array:

```
a.forEach((a)...);
```

To access the objects through an index, use a[0]["Answer"]. The key "Answer" of index 0 in array a.

You need put a type List<Map<String, dynamic>> in your question list to use forEach. Maybe you need use List.From(json) if its comming from a http request.
Like:

```
var questions = [  ... ];
```

and

```
List.from(questions).forEach((q){ ....
```

for example.